# How to run test cases in Chome native client?

Tags: cmake, google-nativeclient, ctest

I'm porting a library to work under Chrome portable native client (PNaCl).  I managed to compile it and run a simple program using it.  Now I need to verify that it works *correctly*, which means running the full test suite.  The library uses CMake for its build system and CTest for the test cases, so each one is a standalone application that runs and returns either 0 or 1 from main() to show if it passed.  How can I run those under native client?

Of course I could modify each one to turn it into a proper module and create an interface for running it.  But there are hundreds of them, and each one would have to be modified independently.  Is there any mechanism for running an existing CTest test suite under native client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option; instead of building Pepper module, you can build a nexe that has main() as its entry point (and doesn't use any Pepper interfaces), which can then be run under sel_ldr, a command-line utility which is included in the SDK (in the pepper_XX/tools directory) and which can run the non-Pepper nexes. If you pass the -a flag to sel_ldr, your nexe can even get local filesystem access, so in general it's useful for things like unit tests.

If you are using the PNaCl toolchain you can build this command-line pexe and then translate it to a nexe offline using the `pnacl-translate` tool in the SDK.

Some more details can be found on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/D3_7Drh47uM)